# Parameterising SQL queries in the following 2 examples

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

In a situations like the below, how would you parameterize the SQL query, especially as the insert booking actually takes place in a different method.

```
// situation 1

for (var i = 0; i < bidList.Count; i++)
{
        var position = i + 1;
        bidList[i].Position = position.ToString();
        query = "UPDATE bid SET position='" + position + "' WHERE status='queued' AND postcode='" + _plot +
                "' AND operator_id='" + bidList[i].OperatorId + "';";
        dbObject.InsertBooking(query);
}

// situation 2

foreach (BidList t in bidList)
{
    query = "SELECT operator_id, plot_id, status FROM booking " +
        "WHERE status='open' AND postcode='" + _plot + "' AND operator_id='0'" +
        "ORDER BY datetime ASC;" +
        "UPDATE booking SET operator_id='" + t.OperatorId + "', status='allocated' " +
        "WHERE (plot_id=" + t.PlotId + " AND operator_id='0' AND status='open') LIMIT 1;";
    dbObject.InsertBooking(query);
} 

// insert booking query

public void InsertBooking(string query)
{
    try
    {
            OpenConnection();

            // Create mysql command
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            // Assign the query using CommandText
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            // Assign the connection using Connection
            cmd.Connection = _connection;

            // Execute query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CloseConnection();
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: With that method, you can't. Have a separate method and either pass a `SqlCommand` object with parameters, or create a method to accept query string and parameters collection. Then build your command and attach parameter to it in the method.

Comment: Ok makes sense - I've decided to do this: http://pastebin.com/E0z92qyS. What do you think?